# Authentication of network connection failed when connecting to the internet

Tags: networking

Authentication of network connection failed when connecting to the internet. I tried changing the DNS, Forgetting the network and connecting again, restarting my laptop and connecting to different neyworks but the same error kept happening. I am running Ubuntu 19.0.4 on an Acer Aspire E5-771 Series notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about connecting to a wireless network. Since Linux isusually is very good at networking, it seems to me, that your laptop may have a hardware, that is not -directly - supported by ubuntu.
Could you paste the result of the following command execute in the the terminal:

```
inxi-n
```

If you have a broadcom driver, you may have to consult the internet in order to get the correct driver. That company is notorious for NOT providing any information about their hardware - some drivers have been reversed engineered in order to run on linux...